# Controlling for semantic shift/change in a dataset

Tags: semantics, language-change

I'm working on a project to ascertain a cohort's feelings (using a Likert scale) on different words relevant to that cohort. Individuals of the cohort are different ages, and the goal is to see if the terms are ranked differently by those of different ages.

The issue is determining "control" words, so to speak, i.e. determining words that are relatively consistent across all ages. I could pick words arbitrarily, but I think that could be problematic. Has anyone looked at words with little semantic shift or change across the last century in the English language? Would there be an open database with that information available?

Thanks so much!